# Keep permanent track of some order in a changing list

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Having a dynamic list of items stored in a database, a external process controls inputs and outputs from this list, which happen in a rate of 1/2 per day.

The items remain in this list for about two weeks.

What I want to do with my program is to assign an order to this list (and store it).

The problem I'm facing is how to properly do this. What value should I save in the database?

I thought about saving the position that it currently is, but this faces the issue that once a item goes out the list (not controlled by me), I must rewrite the order for the rest of them in order to avoid unwanted blank spaces in that order.

Next idea was to save an auto-increasing number and then swap this number between items to change the order. Then to get the real order just sort them by that column. But this will lead to an ever increasing count and doesn't feel right.

What's the proper way to do this?

EDIT: further explanations:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/1ET78nb.png]

This is the part of my program that controls this (forget red color, nothing to do with this). The forth item has been recently added so it has not an order defined. Once I click on up, it should take 4th place and save some value in the database.

Now suppose that in any moment the second or the third value can be eliminated from here, so I can't (well I can but I feel I shouldn't) save just 1,2,3,null in the DB.

Comment: Now I know what is wrong with time - it is "ever increasing count and doesn't feel right" :)

Comment: That depends a lot on what determines the order of your list and whether newer items can auto leap above other ones or not.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Time doesn't feel right to me either!

Comment: Your business rules are not clearly stated, and I don't understand what you are asking.  I suspect that if you could state your desired results clearly, the "how to" would become obvious.

Comment: So you say that I use a big enough field and let it grow up as high as it needs?

Comment: Is the order something visible to the end user?  If so, keep track with some value in the DB where items no longer in the list can be null, then, when you extract from the DB, add a new (c# only) column called order and increment that based on your order as stored in the DB.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-design-a-database-for-storing-a-sorted-list, but it's on a different stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar in the past, and I absolutely stored the numbers 1,2,3,.. as the "Order" column in the database.

And every time somebody clicked the "Up" arrow to move #3 up to #2, the application ran code that changed the 3 to a 2, and the former 2 to a 3.

If #2 got deleted, then the application ran code that moved #3 up to #2, and #4 up to #3, and so on.

And if I were you, that's exactly how I would do it today.

Answer (score 0):

If your program has an integer, which is unique, which defines the order of the record in the database, then just store the position as a field for your records.  If you have a unique constraint, it creates an index for you so sorting by the column will be fast.

Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
  [Id]              BIGINT   NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), -- or some other primary key
  [Position]        INT      NOT NULL,
  -- other columns

  CONSTRAINT [MyTable_Position_UIDX] UNIQUE([Position])
) 
GO
```

Then to access by ordered position

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ORDER BY [Position] DESC
```

EDIT:
Just saw [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-design-a-database-for-storing-a-sorted-list) from another stack exchange site, which is a more correct answer than mine.

Comment: Is the position an integer?

Comment: I can use whichever field I need to define an order, but yes, now it is.

Comment: @Pinx0 updated my answer. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

> The items remain in this list for about **two weeks**.

(follow-up question: how does this external process determine which items to remove from the list?)

> What I want to do with my program is to assign an order to this list
>   (and store it).

(why?  -- doesn't the external process already know how to remove items from the list?  Is there another purpose you're serving by storing a list order?)

> ... unwanted blank spaces ...

(why is that a problem?)

> ever increasing count and doesn't feel right.

(is there a specific thing you're worried about?)

---

As suggested here and elsewhere in the post -- datetime, auto-incremented integers, etc. are all good for sorting.  It's not clear from your post why you need this / what your desired outcome is, so not sure how to better advise, other than just "give it a try!", "go for it", etc.  :-)

Comment: 1- non relevant. manually done.
2- to assist and show what order should be used (a suggestion, not an obligation)